# Exception java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in REST JSON Grails

Tags: json, rest, grails, grails-orm

I used the plugin "JSON RESTful API for GORM" for Grails and I have the next exception:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
Message
String index out of range: -1
Around line 64 of JSONDomainMarshaller.groovy
```

But this only happens when my class domain has a reference to another class domain, the other simple class domain runs perfect.

I hope you can help.